# Quero contabilizar e quantificar os índice Array sobre controle onclick

Tags: javascript, array, paginação

Quero criar uma simples paginação baseada em elementos dentro de um array.

Ao chegar ao primeiro e/ou último elemento do array, gostaria de desabilitar o respectivo botão de navegação (Ex.: mudando de `disabled=false` para `disabled=true`)

## Código

```
<button onclick="Anterior();" id="menos">Anterior</button> &nbsp; 
<span id='numero'>&nbsp;</span> &nbsp; 
<button onclick="Proximo();" id="mais">Próximo</button>

<script>
    var elemento = new Array(1, 2, 3, 2, 7);
    contar = 0

    Proximo = function() {
        contar ++;
              ...
    };

    Anterior = function() {
        contar --;
              ...        
    };

    // retorna o primeiro indice do array
    var menor = document.write(elemento.indexOf(searchElement[, fromIndex])) 
    // retorna o último índice do array
    var maior = document.write(elemento.slice(-1)[0])  

    if (contar == menor) {
        document.getElementById('menos').disabled=true;
    }
    if (contar == maior) {  
        document.getElementById('mais').disabled=true; 
    }
</script>
```

Então ficaria esteticamente assim:

> [ Anterior ]   - 3 -   [ Próximo ]

Gostaria que ele fizesse a contagem dentro do elemento `span`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes fazer assim:

```js
var elemento = new Array(1, 2, 3, 2, 7);

var contar = 0;
var ele_len = elemento.length;
const spn = document.getElementById('numero');
const menos_btn = document.getElementById('menos');
const mais_btn = document.getElementById('mais');
menos_btn.disabled = true;
spn.innerHTML = contar+1;

Proximo = function(btn) {
menos_btn.disabled = false;
contar ++;
spn.innerHTML = contar+1;
if(contar >= ele_len - 1) {
 btn.disabled = true;
 contar = ele_len - 1;
}
};

Anterior = function(btn) {
mais_btn.disabled = false;
contar --;
spn.innerHTML = contar+1;
if(contar <= 0) {
 btn.disabled = true;
 contar = 0;
}
};
```

```html
<button onclick="Anterior(this);" id="menos">Anterior</button> &nbsp; <span id='numero'></span> &nbsp; <button onclick="Proximo(this);" id="mais">Próximo</button>
```

**Dica** - Para mostrar o conteúdo de um *índice* do `Array`, basta trocar as linhas `spn.innerHTML = contar+1;` por esta `spn.innerHTML = elemento[contar];`